# Extracting Day From a Calculated Date Field in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, case, calculated-columns

I am trying to extract the Day from a calulated Field (case Statement) but i keep running into issues. Any advice is appreciated.

```
SELECT 
EXTRACT(DAY FROM (
CASE
 WHEN TYP IN ('Swap')
 THEN LEAST(TRD_DT, VAL_DT)
 ELSE LEAST(EFF_DT, VAL_DT)))
END AS ISS_DT
FROM HA
```

Comment: What issues? On what date values? Please provide more details!

Comment: What are `EFF_DT` , `TRD_DT` and `VAL_DT` ? Are they columns in database tables? What is the data type of each one ?

Comment: One obvious mistake is with parentheses. You have three parentheses after VAL_DT; two of those should be after the keyword `END`, part of the `CASE` expression syntax, on the following line.

Comment: Also, if you extract just the `DAY` from the result of the `CASE` expression, why do you give it the name `ISS_DT` (presumably "issue date")? The result will be a day number, like 12 or 23; `ISS_DT` doesn't seem like a natural name for such a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides fixing the obvious parentheses mismatch, the query can be simplified in a few ways. The full `CASE` expression doesn't need to be in parentheses (although perhaps using them helps some readers). In any case, since the second argument to `LEAST` is the same in both cases, the calculation can be simplified further. I would write that code snippet like so:

```
select extract(day from
          least(case when typ in ('Swap') then trd_dt else eff_dt end, val_dt)
       ) as iss_day
from   ha
```

I use `ISS_DAY` as the column name rather than `ISS_DT`, since what you have is really only a day number, not a date.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for all the suggestions!